# Equation to describe opacity based on percentage

Tags: linear-algebra

I'd like to find an equation where I can input a value of $x$ and return a decimal value between $0$ and $1$. I want the extremes to always return $0$ and the middle to always return $1$, and the ranges close to the extremes to have a linear progression between $0$ and $1$.

I tried modeling it out based on the values I'd like to use, reproduced below, which hopefully should elucidate what I'm after:

```
A = 0.075
B = 0.925
Δ = 0.075

f(0)                    = 0
f(x < A)                = 0
f(A <= x < A + Δ)       = 0 <= y <= 1
f(A + Δ <= x < B - Δ)   = 1
f(B - Δ <= x < B)       = 1 >= y >= 0
f(B <= x)               = 0
f(max)                  = 0
```

No idea if that's a valid way to map an equation, but it made sense to me. Again, I'm not great at Math!

The equation should result in a blocky bell curve, I think:

[image: silly graph]

NOTE: The `1` on the end of the x-axis should read $max$ instead of $1$.

**Context**: I'm creating a video scrub bar, where the ends of the bar have the start and end time for the video (`0:00` and `12:47`, for example). I've also got a pointer that follows your cursor that shows the current time you're hovering over in the range. When your cursor gets close to the edges, I want to fade out the $min$ or $max$ label--depending on whether you're near the start or the end of the bar--so that you don't have to try to read text-on-text.

Other things to note:

- The value for opacity is $0 \le y \le 1$.
- The $max$ value will be a pixel value, for example, `960` (pixels).
- The input for the equation will be a pixel value $0 \le x \le max$.
- $A$, $B$ & $\Delta$ are percentage values, not pixel values.

Please let me know if my question is sensible or if I ommitted important information. My algebra is a bit rusty and I'm stuggling to turn this into a usable equation. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Your question is certainly sensible! It seems to me that you have described the properties of the function you are seeking in full detail. In fact, there is no better or simpler way to represent the function.

Answer (score 1):

I sleuthed around more some algebra sites ([Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra), [MathPapa](https://www.mathpapa.com/), etc.) and eventually remembered about compound inequalities, which is effectively what I wrote in my description of the problem.

So I took a step back and realized I didn't need just one equation, but I could make do with multiple ones, which are easy to tie together programmatically.

Here's what I ended up with for the lower label:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x \le \mathrm{A}$} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $\mathrm{A} + \Delta \lt x$} \\[2ex]
m(x - \mathrm{A}), & \text{if $\mathrm{A} \lt x \le \mathrm{A} + \Delta $}
\end{cases}
$$

... and for the upper label:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $\mathrm{B} \le x$} \\[2ex]
1, & \text{if $x \lt \mathrm{B} - \Delta$} \\[2ex]
m\mathrm{B} - mx, & \text{if $\mathrm{B} - \Delta \le x \lt \mathrm{B}$}
\end{cases}
$$

where

$$m = \frac{\mathrm{A} + 1}{\mathrm{A} + \Delta}$$

... using the lower threshold to solve for $m$, since I know my slope will be the same for both labels (just inverted).

Here's the final javascript that uses the above:

```
const LOWER_THRESHOLD = 0.05;
const UPPER_THRESHOLD = 0.95;
const OPACITY_BUFFER = 0.05; // formerly DELTA

// ...

getOpacityAt(x, thresholdType) {
  const p = x / this.props.totalWidth;
  const m = (LOWER_THRESHOLD + 1) / (LOWER_THRESHOLD + OPACITY_BUFFER);

  if (thresholdType === 'LOWER') {
    if (p <= LOWER_THRESHOLD) return 0;
    if (p > LOWER_THRESHOLD + OPACITY_BUFFER) return 1;

    return m * (p - LOWER_THRESHOLD);
  }

  if (p >= UPPER_THRESHOLD) return 0;
  if (p < UPPER_THRESHOLD - OPACITY_BUFFER) return 1;

  return m * p * -1 + (m * UPPER_THRESHOLD);
}
```

And the final output!

[image: screen capture]

---

I'm still not sure if there is "one" equation that describes this behavior, or if my representations above are correct mathemtaically-speaking, but I've got my end result.

Would love any feedback / improvements!